# How to schedule a BackgroundScheduler job to trigger just 5 mins later (after the app has been started) for the first time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

So, I have a job which runs every day at a fixed time but the first time, I would like it to be run 5 mins after application startup (this is to prevent some uWSGI issue with replicas that I'm seeing). This is what I have so far:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=app.container.config.get("app.timezone"))
job_id = random.randint(0, 999)
job_name = f"mys_fetch_background_job_{job_id}"
    
    # schedule data fetch and run now
scheduler.add_job(
        my_service.fetch_data,
        CronTrigger.from_crontab(
            app.container.config.get("app.my_service.data_reload_cron_utc"), 
            # this value is 0 13 * * *
            "UTC",
        ),
        next_run_time=datetime.time(), # this executes on application startup immediately 
        id=str(job_id),
        name=job_name
)
scheduler.start()
```

I'm trying to figure out how to schedule the first run just 5 mins after application startup - i.e. how can I do : `next_run_time = datetime.time() + 5 mins`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you want the current time from datetime you need to use `datetime.datetime.now()`, as `datetime.time()` will represent a static time (midnight). To get the time 5 minutes from now, you can use a `datetime.timedelta` object like this `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)`. This would work with any `datetime.datetime` object (but not a `datetime.time` object like you used.

Comment: Your suggestion helps! Thank you!!!